# Accessing SearchBar in CollectionView Header Cell - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

At the moment I have a simple **UICollectionReusableView** Class implemented on the CollectionView header cell:

```
class SearchBarCollectionReusableView: UICollectionReusableView {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar:UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var filterSegCtrl:UISegmentedControl!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

I then add this to my **UICollectionViewClass** to show the header below:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String!, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UICollectionReusableView! {

    var reusableview:UICollectionReusableView!

    if kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader {
        let headerView:SearchBarCollectionReusableView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "SearchBar", forIndexPath: indexPath) as SearchBarCollectionReusableView
        reusableview = headerView
    }
    return reusableview
}
```

How do i get access to the UISearchBar properties including *delegates* and *text* in my **UICollectionViewClass** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering with the assumption that you have an instance of your `SearchBarCollectionReusableView` inside your `UICollectionViewClass` which too, under the assumption that it is your `UIView` extended class.

Suppose your `SearchBarCollectionReusableView` variable is `searchBarCRV`. Since all the instance level variables are public in Swift, you can directly access its instance variables. You can get the delegates with something like,

`searchBarCRV.searchBar.delegate = self;`

and text with...

`var searchBarText = searchBarCRV.searchBar.text`

... inside your `UICollectionViewClass`.